# Running a fine-tune model for my CNN : Value Error

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, valueerror

So I am trying to use a pre-trained model on my data set to then compare it to my own cnn model. However, I see an error as soon as I try to do model. fit so much that ((None, 4, 4, 1) vs (None,)). Where is this error coming from? Am I supposed to edit the pre-tune cnn.

The model that I am using is ResNET50 with no modification except the input layer changed to 128 and there are 2 outputs.

Any help is welcome,

CODE:

```
history = modelB.fit_generator(train_data,
                          validation_data = test_data, 
                          epochs=5,
                          steps_per_epoch = 1714,)
```

ERROR:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-89a7f1c1eb60> in <module>()
      2                               validation_data = test_data,
      3                               epochs=5,
----> 4                               steps_per_epoch = 1714,)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1932, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5247, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 4, 4, 1) vs (None,)).
```

Comment: Are you processing the data at any point, either rearranging the date or normalizing the date? Your training data has to match the configuration of the neural network, the issue is not with `history = modelB.fit_generator(train_data, validation_data = test_data, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch = 1714,)` but instead the steps that come before it, since I can not see your configuration it would be impossible to know where the issue resides.

Answer (score 9):

The Issue is with the loss function used when you compile the model.

Replace the compile with below code:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Can you explain what is the cause of the issue?

Comment: The output variables if represented as integers, then you need to use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy. If you use the output as a one hot encoding vector then you can use CategoricalCrossentropy()

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model` to print out a graphic representation of the model.  you have a mismatch between the number of input and output nodes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the loss function in compile with `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` then you can rectify the error.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

First define a loss function to compile like this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.001 ),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          metrics=['accuracy'],)
```

If you still get an error , define pooling  for Resnet model :

```
model_r=tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(
    input_shape=(width,height,3),
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    pooling='avg'
    )
```

This works for me